# print function print lately on time consuming stuff

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, python-3.4

i am trying to understand, why ***start...*** is not print first. but got nothing...

```
from __future__ import print_function
# from time import sleep

def sleeping():
    # sleep(2)
    for i in range(60000000):  # or xrange(60000000)
        pass

print('start...', end='')
sleeping()
print('stop.')
```

same thing happen in this

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep

print('this will print lately')

sleep(2)

print('and this one')
```

i have tried this on both python 3 and 2. on python 2 it works fine.but causes problem on python 3.

**EDIT**:

different output on sublime text and terminal (may be configuration problem on sublime). on terminal, second one works well in both version and first one causes problem in both version.

Comment: Your second example works for me for both python versions. The first one shows the problem, yes?

Comment: @urban may be i haven't configure my sublimetext well for python3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sys.stdout` (which `print` prints to by default) is [line-buffered](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html) when running interactively.

Since `print('start...', end='')` makes the line not end, the output isn't automatically flushed out.

To force the buffer to be flushed, you can specify `flush=True` when calling `print`.

In your case: `print('start...', end='', flush=True)`

Another option is to flush the stream manually by using `sys.stdout.flush()`.

### Further reading:

- [Documentation of `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- [Documentation of `sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)

Comment: Better than mine! I did not know about `flush=True`

Answer (score 2):

The `print` statements are in most of the cases buffered. In order to force print to stdout you have to flush the buffer (using sys):

```
from __future__ import print_function
# from time import sleep
import sys


def sleeping():
    # sleep(2)
    for i in range(60000000):  # or xrange(60000000)
        pass

print('start...', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
sleeping()
print('stop.')
```